# how to use array value in UIView animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

In `UIViewAnimation`, so far i used a single image to animate from one place to another like this:

```
CGRect frame = button.frame;
CGRect frame1 = button1.frame;
frame.origin.x = frame1.origin.x; 
frame.origin.y = frame1.origin.y; 

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationDuration: 3.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{

    [button setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {


}];
button.frame = frame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Here I have nine images in an array:

```
redAppleArray = @[redApple1,redApple2,redApple3,redApple4,redApple5,redApple6,redApple7,redApple8,redApple9,redApple10];
```

I have text display random numbers.

My question is how to get the above text value and animate the image using `UIViewAnimation`? i.e., if `text =3`, `3 redApple` to animate .

Comment: Where is the text? Just converting a string -> number -> array index? Why are you using 2 different forms of animation at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

To get the value from a label for example do:

```
int i = [[myLabel text] intValue];
```

And then use it to get the element in your array:

```
id *redApple = [redAppleArray objectAtIndex:i];
```

Comment: how to give array value to UIView Animation. Because i want to animate  redApple one by one

Answer (score 0):

Try do something lilt this:

```
-(void)yourMethodToAnimateWithText:(NSString*)numberAsAText {
int = [numberAsAText intValue];
CGRect frame = button.frame;
CGRect frame1 = button1.frame;
frame.origin.x = frame1.origin.x; 
frame.origin.y = frame1.origin.y; 

// If you want to add some option use [UIView animateWithDuration:delay:option:animation:completion:]

[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
    //[button setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
    button.frame = frame;
    //Animate your images, text, etc.
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}
```

Hope this is what you after.